# Does LOGLOG = NLOGLOG?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, space-bounded

Define LOGLOG as the class of languages which can be computed in space O(loglog n) by a deterministic Turing machine (with two-way access to the input). Similarly define NLOGLOG as the class of languages which can be computed in space O(log log n) by a non-deterministic Turing machine (with two-way access to the input). Is it really not known that these classes differ?

I could only find some older surveys and a theorem that if they equal then L=NL (which is not just a trivial padding argument!), but somehow I feel that separating these classes cannot be that hard. Of course I might be completely wrong, but if every second bit of the input is the numbers from 1 to n in increasing order in binary, separated by some symbols, then the machines can already learn loglog n and with every other second bit we can input a problem that can fool a deterministic machine but not a non-deterministic one. I don't see yet exactly how this could be done but feels like a possible approach, as with this trick we can basically input a depth log n binary tree along with its structure instead of the usual linear tape.

Comment: From a quick search, I found the paper "Computing with Sublogarithmic Space" by Maciej Liskiewicz and Rudiger Reischuk. Also, it seems that in sublogarithmic space, class relations depend heavily on the model used.

Comment: @chazisop: this is one of the surveys I have also found, everything seems to be at least ten years old on the topic.

Comment: I think @Kaveh is referred to [this post](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3836/1800).

Comment: Thanks! However, this has little to do with my question, the OR obviously won't work here.

Comment: FWIW, I have a vague memory that any language accepted by a single-tape TM running in time $o(n \log n)$ must be regular.  I think the proof is by a crossing-sequence argument.  I don't know the reference.  (I realize this is not directly relevant to your problem, since LOGLOG space does not imply $o(n\log n)$ time, but I thought the crossing-sequence argument for that problem might conceivably be interesting for LOGLOG space as well.)

Comment: Your memory is indeed vague, the theorem is that any TM using o(log log n) space must be regular.

Comment: @domotorp: both statements are theorems, but for $o(n \log n)$ you need single-tape. (Of course, for $SPACE(o(\log \log n))$ you can also assume one-tape, since the multi-tape to one-tape translation doesn't increase space.) The reference Neal Young was looking for is: Kobayashi (1985) (http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(85)90165-3) building off of Hennie (1965) (http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0019-9958(65)90399-2), who showed that linear-time one-tape TMs decide only regular languages and introduced crossing sequences.

Comment: Here's a strawman candidate for separating the two:
the language
$L' = \{0,1,\#\}^*\, L\, \{0,1,\#\}^*$
where $L$ is 
$\{b_k(0)\#b_k(1)\#\cdots\#b_k(2^k-1)\# ~~|~ k=1,2,3,\ldots\}$,
where $b_k(i)$ is the $k$-bit binary representation of $i$.
$L$ is in LOGLOG
[[reference](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/PS/CC/l4.ps)],
so I'm pretty sure $L'$ is in NLOGLOG.
Can anyone show $L'$ is (or is not) in LOGLOG?

Comment: Wow, I feel ashamed that I did not know this theorem, thanks for the links! Also, I think L' is in LOGLOG as we can just try running the algorithm for L at every sequence of all 0's and if we fail, we can go to the next sequence of all 0's.

Comment: But with just LOGLOG space, it is not clear to me how to keep track of the current starting point.  Perhaps you can modify the algorithm for L so that if, during its computation, it finds "#00..0#" (invalidating the current try), then it resets and starts over at that new #00..0#".

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind.

Comment: The problem is intriguing.  Here is a problem that seems related: can any $n$-state two-way non-deterministic finite automata be simulated by a poly$(n)$-state two-way deterministic finite automata?  From [these talk slides](http://pighizzini.di.unimi.it/talks/2010/Porto.pdf), it appears that the answer is unknown.   Curiously, this question restricted to *unary* languages (roughly, with some assumptions) is apparently equivalent to whether L = NL.

Answer (score 18):

The [entry in the complexity zoo](http://complexity-zoo.net/zoo/wiki/Complexity_Zoo%3aL#loglog) is surprisingly detailed; it claims that 
**NLOGLOG** = **co-NLOGLOG** in the paper

> [Nondeterministic computations in sublogarithmic space and space constructibility](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=114454), Viliam Geffert, SIAM Journal on Computing, 1991.

But after a brief reading, I do not see any claim about the fact that NLOGLOG is closed under complement; maybe a deeper look is needed.
And the main result they have is that there are no nondeterministic fully space-constructible unbounded monotone increasing $s(n)$ functions for $s(n) = o(\log n)$. It is known that if such functions exists, then

$\mathsf{SPACE}[s(n)] \neq \mathsf{NSPACE}[s(n)]$.

And in the conclusion the author claimed that " ...this main separation problem remains *open*. "

As @chazisop said, the relations of these low-level complexity classes are depended on the models, and it is stated in the entry of the zoo that

> "There are several possible definitions of this class; the most common is the class of languages which can be computed in space O(log log n) by a deterministic Turing machine with two-way access to the input. "

Which is coincident to your definition and also the paper's.

Comment: I think it only claims NLOGLOG=co-NLOGLOG. I also could not find this statement in the abstract of the paper, though I could not open the full paper.

Comment: @domotorp: You are right. I feel really embarrassing to my wrong answer... I'm too tired even misread the sentences, Maybe I should take a break for Christmas.

Answer (score 1):

If LOGLOG = NLOGLOG then LOG = NLOG. See more in:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397590900086

and therefore, your question is still an unsolved problem.

Comment: This is one of the papers I was referring to when I wrote "I could only find some older surveys and a theorem that if they equal then L=NL".